# How can I rumble/vibrate my controller with libGDX?

Tags: libgdx, mobile, controllers

The `com.badlogic.gdx.controllers.Controllers` API only supports getting the input data (which works fine).

Is there a way to make my controller rumble/vibrate, possibly using some other classes?

I tried using the `org.lwjgl.input.Controllers` class, which supports this, but the controllers don't get indexed there and I can not access them.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not supported by now: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2057 But maybe this will work for you https://github.com/StrikerX3/JXInput ?

Comment: JXInput worked for me. Once I linked the libraries properly it was just a matter of a few lines of code. Just be aware, there's another Java lib called JXInput out there that's not the same thing.

Comment: JXInput is not cross-platform :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make my controller rumble/vibrate, possibly using some other classes?

It's not a feature libGDX itself supports, and it seems unlikely (based on the [discussion on the issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/2057) linked in the comments) to happen any time soon. You'll have to use third-party libraries.

Unfortunately most of those third-party libraries (like [JXInput](https://github.com/StrikerX3/JXInput)) map to the native XInput API to provide vibration (for 360 controllers), which means they don't function on non-Windows system. Regular [JInput](https://github.com/jinput/jinput) seems like it may be hampered by the same issue, and doesn't seem to expose vibration anyhow. There are native libraries like [libstem_gamepad](https://github.com/ThemsAllTook/libstem_gamepad) you could wrap, but *they* don't support vibration either.

With the caveat that I haven't really tried it, your best bet might be to use the [Java binding for SDL](http://sdljava.sourceforge.net/), possibly only for the controller APIs, and try to leverage the [haptic feedback API](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HapticOpenFromJoystick) therein.

Answer (score 1):

For using SDL with libGDX desktop, you can use [Jamepad](https://github.com/williamahartman/Jamepad). It supports rumbling. There are wrappers for Jamepad to use it as a drop-in replacement for the libGDX controller implementation, for example [gdx-controllerutils](https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-controllerutils/wiki/Jamepad-controller-implementation).

Now, a problem is that you can't trigger rumbling with the existing implementations: libGDX' controller interface just don't have a method for doing so. The task still to do is:

- make an own Controller interface extending libGDX' interface with methods for rumbling
- implement this interface in [JamepadController](https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-controllerutils/blob/master/desktop-jamepad/src/main/java/de/golfgl/gdx/controllers/jamepad/support/JamepadController.java)
- check with `instanceof` in your core code if you have an Controller implementing your interface and then rumble

Best was if the libGDX' controller interface would be extended. There are other methods lacking as well, for example requesting how many buttons and axis are present. Apparently, there is not much interest in the controller extension by the maintainers, so you are better off with an own solution described above.